# How to make large copying operations in python more efficient

Tags: python-3.x, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, copy-paste

I am trying to parallelize my code to make it faster.

I have four lists which stores paths to files as strings. I have to copy these files from each list to a particular folder.

This is my copying function

```
def copy_machine(eegs,cls):
    if cls == 1:
        for eeg in eegs:
            dest = shutil.copyfile(eeg,class_1+eeg[-22:])
    if cls == 2:
        for eeg in eegs:
            dest = shutil.copyfile(eeg,class_2+eeg[-22:])
    if cls == 3:
        for eeg in eegs:
            dest = shutil.copyfile(eeg,class_3+eeg[-22:])
    if cls == 12:
        for eeg in eegs:
            dest = shutil.copyfile(eeg,class_12+eeg[-22:])


copy_machine(eegs_1,1)
copy_machine(eegs_2,2)
copy_machine(eegs_3,3)
copy_machine(eegs_12,12)
```

But I have a total of 13000+ files to copy and this method is taking too much time. So I am trying to make it more efficient.

Is there any better/faster ways of copying in python? If not, How do I parallelize this code to make it faster?

Comment: Copying tens of thousands of files will likely be fairly slow whatever the language and possibly in parallel too. Do you have an SSD or an HDD? Which filesystem? If you have an SSD, how many IOPS can be achieved with it? What do you mean by "slow" (seconds/minutes/hours)?

Comment: How big are the files on average? And how long does it currently take?

Comment: The answer also depends on your network infrastructure/topology, and storage infrastructure. It might be fastest to copy the files from Host A to Host B then tell Host B to copy the files to Host C while Host A copies to Host D. It might be fastest to NFS/Samba mount the files to each host so they can access the files themselves. If your storage is a SAN, it might be quicker to switch the entire volume to each host in turn. It may be fastest to make a `tar` file and scp/FTP that between hosts. If your machines are on a slow network and you have TB of data, a truck full of tapes may be fastest.